# How can I get the exact value of this infinite series?

Tags: summation

I want to compute the exact value of this infinite series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\arcsin{\left(\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1})}\right)}$$

I tried to implement something like this

```
  Sum[ArcSin[2/((-Sqrt[-1 + n] + Sqrt[n]) Sqrt[n (1 + n)])],{n,1,Infinity}]
```

but it does not work because  I run this code get the same expression

```
 Sum[ArcSin[2/((-Sqrt[-1 + n] + Sqrt[n]) Sqrt[n (1 + n)])],{n,1,Infinity}]
```

not the exact value I want . Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: ...and you're absolutely sure this is supposed to have a closed form?

Comment: @J. M. The series converges.

Comment: Yes, it does. That does not guarantee the existence of a known closed form tho. In this case, *Mathematica* is effectively saying "I don't know what to do."

Comment: @J. M. If so ,How can I evaluate the sum ?

Comment: `NSum[]` will be able to give an approximation.

Comment: @user250236; I am getting a complex number for the sum. Are you sure you would rather not use 2 to infinity for the indices.

Comment: @J. M. from `NSum[ArcSin[2/((Sqrt[n] + Sqrt[n - 1]) Sqrt[(n + 1) n])], {n, 2, Infinity}]` I get  `1.57713 `.How can I get 1.577134230124889513864011795293057977459257178812501378053524 by applying  `Nsum[ ] `

Comment: @bobbym :I think we'd better use 2 to infinity for the indices.

Comment: @user250236; Why do you feel that all those digits are correct?